# Is it possible to store a resulting php variable into localStorage?

Tags: javascript, php, storage, local

I have seen a lot of people asking about the reverse, but what i need to do is store a string resulting from php script into localStorage?

Currently, my approach is to store the data in an attribute inside of an html element on my page like this:

```
<div id="php-data" data-php-value="<?= $var ?>"></div>
```

and then retrieve the value with JS and store it like this:

```
let phpVarStorage = document.getElementById("php-data");
let phpValue = phpVarStorage.getAttribute("data-php-value");

localStorage.setItem('php_var', phpValue);
```

I am just not thrilled with this approach, but I assume there are no PHP methods for storing data client side.

Can anyone offer another approach?

Comment: Just skip the whole HTML to Javascript thing and go straight for the Javascript ? `localStorage.setItem('php_var', "<?= $var ?>");`

Comment: interesting, i do like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store directly like this, as long as you got PHP has this data with you in the same page

```
<script>
   localStorage.setItem('php_var', "<?php echo $var;?>");
</script>
```

Comment: Ensure that `$var` has double quote escaped to prevent JavaScript error and potential XSS attacks

Comment: Simply replace `$var` to `str_replace( "\"", "\\\"", $var )` would do

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can save it directly like this

```
localStorage.setItem('php_var', "<?=$var;?>");
```